# How to fit a power law to the dataframe and plot it?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy

I have two columns(rcs,range) in a dataframe.

| rcs | range |
| --- | --- |
| -40 | 12.9 |
| -35 | 14.9 |
| -30 | 22.9 |
| -25 | 35.44 |
| -20 | 43.48 |
| -15 | 62.4 |
| -10 | 92.4 |
| -5 | 132.99 |
| 0 | 182.6 |
| 5 | 252.99 |

I want to plot a curve with equation rcs = range^4

I tried the following
1.as a polynomial curve fitting

```
def curve_gen(x,a,b,c,d,e):  #for polynomial
    return (a*(x**4))+(b*(x**3))+(c*(x**2))+(d*x)+e

y = df['rcs'].values
x = df['range'].values
pop,_ = curve_fit(curve_gen,x,y)
a,b,c,d,e = pop
pl.scatter(y,x)
pl.plot(curve_gen(x,a,b,c,d,e),x,color = 'red')
pl.show()
```

[image]
**in the above plot,the curve is not a smooth curve and is not starting from -40**

2.power law curve fit

```
def power_law(x,a):  
    return a*np.power(x,4)

y = df['rcs'].values
x = df['range'].values
pop,_ = curve_fit(power_law,x,y)
a = pop
pl.scatter(y,x)
pl.plot(power_law(x,a),x,color = 'red')
pl.show()
```

this one giving me a wrong plot.the red line is not passing through the blue points
[image]

how to solve the above issue using curve_fit?and plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.polyfit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) and [`numpy.poly1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html):

```
# initial data
plt.plot(df['rcs'], df['range'], marker='o', ls='', label='data')

# fit
fit = np.polyfit(df['rcs'], df['range'], deg=4)
# array([1.87062937e-05, 4.24655012e-03, 3.34652273e-01, 1.20759569e+01,
#        1.83604091e+02])

# get X range
X = np.arange(df['rcs'].min(), df['rcs'].max()+1)
# plot mapped fit onto X
plt.plot(X, np.poly1d(fit)(X), label='fit')
```

output:

[image: polynomial fit]

Comment: is there any way to find the equation of curve?

Comment: `fit` contains the coefficients, `poly1d` avoids to have to manually type: `fit[0]*X**4+fit[1]*X**3+fit[2]*X**2+fit[3]*X+fit[4]`